# CMake tests fails but if just run testing executable so everything is ok

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, qt5

I'm using mingw (4.9.1) that was stored with last Qt official build. CMake version is 3.1.2. The situation is when i called `make test` so i got failed tests with exceptions, but, if i just run this test *.exe by manually — everything is ok, tests running!
What can be wrong? 
And yes, I checked the libs its liked with...
There are these files...

CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0020 NEW)

#ENABLE_TESTING( true )

SET( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )
SET( CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON )

SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QTDIR})

FIND_PACKAGE( Qt5Core REQUIRED )
FIND_PACKAGE( Qt5Test REQUIRED )


ADD_EXECUTABLE( coretest coretest.cpp )
ADD_TEST( coretest coretest )

QT5_USE_MODULES( coretest Core Test )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( coretest ${QT_LIBRARIES} )
```

And single test code file (coretest.cpp):

```
#include <QTest>

class Coretest : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void t1();
};

void Coretest::t1()
{
    QVERIFY(true);
}

QTEST_MAIN(Coretest)
#include "coretest.moc"
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just having a slow day, but this title isn't making sense to me... Does this need punctuation somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got the solution. Just forget to check Path var...

Comment: This is an attempt at a self-answer, albeit not a very informative one.